# convert blob per record to blob and then return as a json response

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, base64

Assume I have 6 records in the database table and each of the record has 'blob' and I want to convert that 'blob' from each record into a base64 string. I know I can just use

```
base64_encode($data)
```

but the problem is I don't know how to loop through each record, get its 'blob and convert it into base64. This is the way I retrieve the records (refer below)

```
$vote = users_details::where('vote', '=', 1)->get(['firstname', 'middlename', 'lastname', 'branch', 'position', 'img']);
```

and return as a json response (refer below)

```
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'vote' => $vote ]);
```

so any suggestions, recommendations, clues, help to achieve what I want please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the `img` column is the blob you're referring to. If that is so you can either loop through the [Collection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections) of users you're getting in `$vote` with help of the [map](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-map) method:

```
$vote = $vote.map(function ($v) {
    return base64_encode($v->img);
}
```

or if you always want the img to be returned as a base64 string you could use a [mutator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) in your User model.

```
public static function getImgAttribute($value)
{
    return base64_encode($value);
}
```

---

*As a side note. You might want to choose a better name for `$vote` as it's not really a vote, but a Collection of users that has vote set to 1. It will be easier for you to understand what you have done when you get back to your code after a while. And easier for other people to understand the code if you'll be collaborating with someone.*

*I'm not sure what the vote column is for, but maybe `$votedUsers` or `$usersWithVote` would be a good name? Or `$voted_users` / `$users_with_vote` if you prefer snake_case*